# In Angular2 using Observables, how to identify when the subscribed observable has a value?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am subscribed to an observable and in case one of the values in the object comes empty I need to supply a default value.  The thing is that when I actually have a value it still takes the default.  Please see my current approach below:

**Using the setTimeout in ngOnInit (my understanding is that ngOnChanges executes first, and then ngOnInit):**

```
           ngOnInit() {
                setTimeout(() => {     
                     this.checkEmptyDescription(this.ntData.description);//this method checks for an empty this.ntData.description

                    }, 0);    
                }
```

**ngOnChanges**:

```
        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
            this.loadData();

        }
        private checkEmptyDescription(notes: string) {
            if (notes === null || notes === undefined || notes.trim() === '') {
                this.editedDescription = this.defaultDescription;
            }
            else {
                this.editedDescription = this.ntData.description;
            }
        }

protected loadData() {
    this._ntDataStr.getNoteData(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.ntData= data;


    });

}
```

**Update**

This is another approach I used:

```
protected loadData() {
    this._ntDataStr.getNoteData(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.ntData= data;
        this.editedDescription = this.ntData.description || this.defaultDescription ;


    });

}
```

Comment: Why you're using `setTimeout()` and why you can't initialize object properties with just `public editedDescription: number = 42` or in the constructor?

Comment: Where you are binding the `ntData.description` can't you just use `ntData.description || <defaultValue>`?  That's a little broad, so you may want to put more qualifiers on it, but if you're not concerned about catching false negatives (0, "" or some such), then that should let it populate with whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you.  @Dave I tried that and it didn't work.  Martin, these properties are public, I don't follow...the property editedDescription would need to change in case it has a description, am I making any sense?

Comment: @DaveV, let me update my post with what I had done, I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @eagleEye what happens if you keep only `ngOnChanges`? and are you sure that `data.description` received from `getNoteData` has a value?

Comment: Thanks @OferHerman, let me try that.  Yes, the method does return a value.  Initially I didn't have to provide a default value when empty to the description, so whatever the server returned I was able to display w/o issues.